# Quick Launch Bar Wrap Text

Tags: master-page, content-editor-web-part, quick-launch, html

Currently, my page titles in the quick launch bar are wrapping in the middle of the text.  My objective is to have the word not be broken into two. However, I **do not** want to change the Master page.  So, can I use a Script Editor to fix this issue?  If so, would it script to change the title or the quick launch bar?  By the way, I only want this to appear on one page not all, therefore, I thought a script editor web part for that page would be the easiest, but I am not sure if it's possible.  For example, please view the images below.  Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Before 
[image]

After
[image]

***UPDATE***
I tried this code in a script editor.  Not working.  Can you tell me what I have done wrong? Thanks!

```
<style type ="text/css">
  .menu-item-text span { word-wrap: normal; } 
</style> 

<span class="menu-item-text">
  <span>SharePoint 2013 Workflows</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I'm runing SP build 15.0.4569.1000 and links in Quick Launch are properly word wrapped: http://i.imgur.com/Q3Pw9fk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled with the word-wrap CSS property (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).  Basically, just set the "word-wrap" style to "normal" on the element containing the text.

Comment: Thank you, John Chapman. So, I would add the following into the script editor:                                                     <style type="text/css">

.ms-tag //place the quick launch bar tag here 

{Word-Wrap: normal
;}


</style>

Comment: Yes, something to that effect.  If the style tag gets stripped out of the script editor, you can use a content editor web part.  You may have to experiment a little with which class to target (you can use the IE Developer Toolbar, FireFox FireBug, or the Chrome Developer Console to test it on the page before actually applying it to the site).

Comment: Thank you, John Chapman.  I updated the question with the code.  For some reason it's not working. I am still testing.  Thanks.